# JSON Schema Validation using a wildcard character

Tags: ruby, jsonschema

Consider a string value :
"equal to (=23)\nequal to (=45)". How to specify this in a json schema in such a manner that in place of 23 and 45, any number can come?

Comment: Hi! Did you try anything yet? This looks like homework to me, so please explain how we can help your in your attempt.

Answer (score 2):

The `pattern` keyword lets you specify a regular expression for a string, for example:

```
{
    "type": "string",
    "pattern": "^equal to [0-9]+5$"
}
```

The expression is not anchored by default, so you'll probably want to use `^`/`$` to specify the start and end.